# Load scenes inactive

Tags: unity, c#

When I call `SceneManager.LoadScene()` it will set the loaded scene as active.  Can I load scenes at the game startup and just call `SceneManager.SetActiveScene()` during gameplay?

If so, is there a way to iterate through all the scenes in the *Build Settings* and load them?  Mine don't have a build index assigned to them until I have called `LoadScene()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is **async** loading. async loading, just loads you scene in background and shows(runs) you scene anytime you want.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html
[Smooth loading screen between scenes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/130180/smooth-loading-screen-between-scenes)

Comment: Ah.  OK, I assumed it was identical to the synchronous version, just async.